# Character representation from hexadecimal

Tags: javascript, c, string, hex, ascii

Is it possible to convert a hexadecimal value to its respective ASCII character, not using the `String.fromCharCode` method, in JavaScript?

For example:

**JavaScript:**

```
0x61 // 97 
String.fromCharCode(0x61) // a
```

**C-like:**

```
(char)0x61 // a
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `.fromCharCode()`?

Comment: @JamWaffles: Just out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not in that fashion, because JavaScript is loosely typed, and does not allow one to define a variable's data type.

What you can do, though, is creating a shortcut:

```
var char = String.fromCharCode; // copy the function into another variable
```

Then you can call `char` instead of `String.fromCharCode`:

```
char(0x61); // a
```

Which is quite close to what you want (and perhaps more readable/requiring less typing).

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `\xNN` notation:

```
var str = "\x61";
```

Comment: Can you do something like var str = "\x61\x62\x61\x41" to get the string "abaA" ?

Answer (score 8):

There is also the Unicode equivalent of `\x`:

```
var char = "\u0061";
```